# REACT/REDUX: How to connect Store to the App component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to make my main  component state aware without creating additional files, if possible... Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const App = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
                <>
                    <p>...AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <p>...NOT AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            )}
        </Provider>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.mode.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I get error : ***"Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options."***

I tried changing my code, but it didn't work

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const AppWithStore = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    );
};

const App = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
                <>
                    <p>...AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <p>...NOT AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.mode.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithStore);
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Provider` "makes the redux store available to any *nested* components." - https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#overview

You don't want to "connect" your component with the `Provider` (AppWithStore), you want to "connect" any children of `Provider` (App)

Based on your second example:

You need to `connect` your `App` component, not `AppWithStore`

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Then be sure you're default exporting `AppWithStore`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

let App = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
                <>
                    <p>...AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <p>...NOT AUTHED...</p>
                </>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.mode.isAuthenticated
});

App = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const AppWithStore = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    );
};


export default AppWithStore;
```